# Different data counts, but same storage size in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I insert json data to mongodb.
First time, I insert 40,000 data counts to mongodb, I use command db.stats() and I get storage size is 315,080,704 bytes.
And I drop data.
Second time, I insert 50,000 data counts to mongodb, I get storage size is 315,080,704 bytes, too. 
But their data size are different, first is 246,559,504 bytes and second is 308,182,432 bytes.
Why they have same storage size?

Comment: statement of yours `I get storage size is 315,080,704 bytes, too. 
But their data size are different`, So you know the difference between data size and storage size then why you posted the question.

Comment: @karthick.k: it's not evident to me (from the question) that he knows what storage size is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

storageSize is the amount allocated for storing data. Not the actual amount of data. Say, you have a refrigerator bag with capacity of 24 cans. You try to insert 30 cans of beer in there. After 24th can you have to add another bag. After this operation you have

```
dataSize: 30 cans
storageSize: 48 cans
```

More info about different numbers from `db.stats()`: http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/01/how-big-is-your-mongodb/